# upper bound of an $L^\infty$ function's derivative

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods

Consider a function $u:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that
is essentially bounded, i.e., $u \in L^\infty$. There is an upper bound of its derivative? I think there is not allways ( i.g. $\sqrt{x} \ x \in (0,1)$). But what quality of the $L^\infty $ functions assures that they have also bounded derivatives?

I am considering the numerical solution of an ODE, $\dot{y} = f(t,y) \ y(0)=y_0$, each point of the solution $\{y_i,t_i\}$  is glued with a straight line, this gives a piecewise $C^\infty$ function $v:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. The error $e= y(t) - v(t)$ has a bounded euclidean norm $\| e \| \le K$ and also the derivatives **of this norm** lower dini derivative that is bounded: $D_+ \|e\| < M$, now a need the upper bound for $\| D_+ e \|$.

Comment: I don't think there is any such quality intrinsic to $L^\infty$. Perhaps you're looking for $L^\infty$ functions of bounded variation?

Comment: What is the derivative of an $L^\infty$ function? It is not even defined in the normal sense. In general, functions with a uniformly bounded derivative are Lipschitz continuous, maybe you are looking for that?

Comment: yes! you’re right Lukas, that derivative is not defined! I forgot to say that $y$ is absolutely continuous and $v$ is derivable almost everywhere. Now $e$ is not only $L^\infty$ but is also... I don't know... absolutely continuous? So an $L^\infty$ function that is also derivable almost everywhere has bounded derivative?